# Apache - Only allow to open files located in a specific folder via URL

Tags: apache

I am useing the following folder structure:

```
    localhost
        server
            php
                docs
                classes
                errors
                ...
        client
            css
            javascript
            ...
```

All documents which should be opened by the user via url are located in the server/php/docs directory.

```
localhost/server/docs/index.php
localhost/server/docs/any_other_document_in_this_folder.php
```

But something like this should not be possible:

```
localhost/server/classes/language.php   
localhost/server/errors/error404.php  
localhost/client/javascript/buttonhandler.js
```

How can I forbid the user to open files on this way?

Answer (score 0):

I am using now 5 redirects. Maybe it is possible to use not as much.

```
RedirectMatch "^/$" "/server/php/docs/index.php"
RedirectMatch "^\/(server)\/(php)\/((?!docs).*)$" "/server/php/docs/index.php"
RedirectMatch "^\/(client).*$" "/server/php/docs/index.php"
RedirectMatch "^\/(server|client)\/$" "/server/php/docs/index.php"
RedirectMatch "^\/(server)\/((?!php).*)$" "/server/php/docs/index.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

My posted solution does not work. Every url used in documents in the directory

```
server/php/docs
```

is redirected. Also stuff like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../client/vendor/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

So my question is: is it possible (and how) that the user is not able to open URLs as I posted at the very beginning? I would prefer that in this case the user is redirected to

```
localhost/server/php/docs/index.php
```